# Remove Duplicate URLs from Elements list in jSoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

When using jSoup to scrape a page, all of the links on the page can be gathered using;

```
Elements allLinksOnPage = doc.select("a");
```

Which is great. Now how would one go about removing duplicate URLs from this list? I.e. imagine a /contact-us.html that is linked in both the main navigation.

Once all the duplicate URLs have been removed, then the next step is to crawl those unique URLs and continue the loop.

A question on the practicalities of this though. For the code;

```
for (Element e : allLinksOnPage) {
    String absUrl = e.absUrl("href");

    //Asbolute URL Starts with HTTP or HTTPS to make sure it isn't a mailto: link
    if (absUrl.startsWith("http") || absUrl.startsWith("https")) {
        //Check that the URL starts with the original domain name
        if (absUrl.startsWith(getURL)) {
            //Remove Duplicate URLs
            //Not sure how to do this bit yet?
            //Add New URLs found on Page to 'allLinksOnPage' to allow this 
            //For Loop to continue until the entire website has been scraped
        }
    }
}
```

So the question being, the final part of the loop, imagine when page-2.html is crawled, more URLs are identified on here and added to the allLinksOnPage variable.

Will the for loop continue for the length of the full list, i.e. 10 links found on page-1.html and 10 links on page-2.html, so 20 pages will be crawled in total - OR - Will the loop only continue for the length of the first 10 links identified, i.e. the links before the code 'for (Element e : allLinksOnPage)' is triggered?

This will all inevitably end up in a database once the logic is finalised, but looking to keep the logic purely Java based initially to prevent lots of reads/writes to the DB which will slow everything down.

Comment: you could use a set to store the urls and then check for every url if it has been already processed. btw `absUrl.startsWith("http") || absUrl.startsWith("https")` is redundant. You can drop the `startswith("https)` part

Comment: Thanks @MadMatts Yes that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`allLinksOnPage` is iterated only once. You never retrieve any information about pages you found links to.

You can use a `Set` and a `List` for this, however. Furthermore you can use the `URL` class to extract the protocol for you.

```
URL startUrl = ...; 
Set<String> addedPages = new HashSet<>();
List<URL> urls = new ArrayList<>();
addedPages.add(startUrl.toExternalForm());
urls.add(startUrl);
while (!urls.isEmpty()) {
     // retrieve url not yet crawled
     URL url = urls.remove(urls.size()-1);

     Document doc = JSoup.parse(url, TIMEOUT);
     Elements allLinksOnPage = doc.select("a");
     for (Element e : allLinksOnPage) {
        // add hrefs
        URL absUrl = new URL(e.absUrl("href"));

        switch (absUrl.getProtocol()) {
            case "https":
            case "http":
                if (absUrl.toExternalForm().startsWith(getURL) && addedPages.add(absUrl.toExternalForm())) {
                    // add url, if not already added
                    urls.add(absUrl);
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's perfect, thanks @fabian . I've just been testing this on a variety of sites and noticed that a lot of sites have links to URLs with # in then which are simply duplicates of the same URL. I'll open a new question for this one for how to normalise the URL fully as it is outside of the scope of this question.